# remove duplicate characters in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to apply a filter that removes duplicate characters in solr 
eg (cool -> col)

I looked at the filters and the tokenizers but all I can find is a tokenizer that removes duplicate tokens.

RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory

what is the way to do this for letters/characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory with a regex to remove any identical characters after each other. The replacement string is `$1` (the first matching group), and the matching pattern is `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{1,}` - any letter, followed by the same letter (`\1`), at least once (`{1,}`). This will also replace `coool` with `col`.

An example field type definition to the Schema API:

```
{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"removeDoubleLettersField",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
        "charFilters":[{
           "class":"solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory",
           "replacement":"$1",
           "pattern":"([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1{1,}" }],
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" },
        "filters":[{
           "class":"solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory",
           "preserveOriginal":"0" }]}}
}
```